# Java projects and git repositories

Tags: java, git, class, jar, package

I'm working on two projects. One of them is a library that has some classes such as `Neuron.java`, `ANN.java`, etc. The other one is a visualization program that uses those classes and runs some simulations, and then displays the results.

I intended for these two projects to have a different name and be in separate git repositories. There is a problem, though. All of my project directories (in which I plan to keep the `.git/` directory, the documentation, the classes and a `.jar` file of all the classes) reside in `com/yannbane/`.

If I declare my classes as belonging to the `com.yannbane.library` package (for example), how will someone that downloads the repo be able to use the library if he doesn't have the same folder structure?

Will it be easier for me to simply abandon `com/yannbane` and just keep all projects in completely separate directories and belonging to their own, separate packages? If I do so, I will have to share the `.jar` file of the library between the projects myself, right?

Comment: @Perception, I think this is a fundamental problem in my understanding of Java as a platform. I'd like to solve this myself, without using any managers like IDEs or, what you have suggested, Maven, until I understand how things are supposed to work. Thanks for the recommendation, though, it might be useful later!

Comment: This is not a 'Java as a platform' issue, its a library packaging one. You can insist on rolling your own, but in the end you will find a tool dedicated to the cause infinitely more useful. Good luck!

Comment: Hm, well, but it still falls under the "common methods and practices" I guess. Sure, I will use many tools later on, but I'm starting bottom up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the package structure of your code should be inside the repository.

You don't need to use Maven or an IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse) but you could use the same kind of structure to organize your code.

I would have something like:

```
Library/
        .git/
        src/
            com/
                yanbanne
        libs/
             dependencyL1.jar
             dependencyL2.jar
        dist/
             library.jar
             library.doc

Visualization/
              .git/
              src/
                  com/
                      yanbanne
              libs/
                   dependencyV1.jar
                   dependencyV2.jar
                   library.jar
              dist/
                   visualization.jar
                   visualization.doc
```

The `lib` folders could be omitted using tools like Maven or Ivy. Copying `library.jar` to the dependencies of *Visualization* could be done automatically by establishing a dependency among projects in an IDE, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Great, I was hoping for something like that! But how do I use classes from `Library` in `Visualization`? JAR?

Comment: Also, I'm waiting for some peer review on this method, but I'll probably accept your answer.

Comment: Well, you'd copy the `library.jar` to the same directory where you keep other dependencies of `Visualization`. Let me add a few lines...

Comment: Great, that's complete now! Thanks.